# BackStack Implementation for Fragments in android Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, out-of-memory

My Android Application Requires Iphone Kind of design like having tabs and multiple internal screens. I am done with app development and now facing OutOfMemoryError if I use the app for long time. So I done googling and found that setting Activities inside Tabs will consume more memory and I am using replace() in FragmentTransactions to change the Fragments. So when clicking on the back key Fragments views are re-created which are very much expensive in my app are also consuming lot of memory. So I want to change my app architecture by setting view directly to the Tabs and implementing the own back stack for Fragments Navigation. I have implemented the below code and it is working fine but using show/Hide for the entire app process is good or not? Can some one suggest me an example of implementing backstack or correct me in the below code.

```
package com.fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnTabChangedListener {
    ArrayList<Fragment> alTab1 = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    ArrayList<Fragment> alTab2 = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TabHost tabHost = findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();
        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        photospec.setContent(R.id.tab1content);
        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        videospec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
        videospec.setContent(R.id.tab2content);
    tabHost.addTab(photospec);
tabHost.addTab(videospec);
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Tab1Fragment1 t1f1 = new Tab1Fragment1();
            ft.add(R.id.tab1content, t1f1, "t1f1");
            addToBackStack(t1f1);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if (tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0) {
        }
        if (tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1) {
            if (alTab2.size() == 0) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                if (fm != null) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    Tab2Fragment1 t2f1 = new Tab2Fragment1();
                    ft.add(R.id.tab2content, t2f1, "t2f1");
                    addToBackStack(t2f1);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void addToBackStack(Fragment f) {
        if (tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0) {
            if (alTab1.size() > 0) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                ft.hide(alTab1.get(alTab1.size() - 1));
                ft.commit();
            }
            alTab1.add(f);
        }
        if (tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1) {
            if (alTab2.size() > 0) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                ft.hide(alTab2.get(alTab2.size() - 1));
                ft.commit();
            }
            alTab2.add(f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0) {
            if (alTab1.size() > 1) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                ft.remove(alTab1.get(alTab1.size() - 1));
                alTab1.remove(alTab1.size() - 1);
                ft.show(alTab1.get(alTab1.size() - 1));
                ft.commit();
                return;
            }
        }
        if (tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1) {
            if (alTab2.size() > 1) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                ft.remove(alTab2.get(alTab2.size() - 1));
                alTab2.remove(alTab2.size() - 1);
                ft.show(alTab2.get(alTab2.size() - 1));
                ft.commit();
                return;
            }
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: did yo get the answer... then pls help ne........